# Stanford CoreNLP: Building Error (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: netbeans, maven, nlp, stanford-nlp

Sorry if this is a newbie's question.
I was trying to use maven in Netbeans to build CoreNLP parser.

I first added dependency of stanford-corenlp 1.2.0. However, I always got an error while compiling my code. I tried to simplify my code to just create the StanfordCoreNLP object, but it still did not function with the same error message. I guess here might come with the main trouble spot then.

My simplified code shows as:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.factory
(Ledu/stanford/nlp/process/LexedTokenFactory;Ljava/lang/String;)Ledu/stanford/nlp/objectbank/TokenizerFactory;
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.PTBTokenizerAnnotator.<init>(PTBTokenizerAnnotator.java:42)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$1.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:365)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$1.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:355)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:62)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:328)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:194)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:184)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:176)
        at com.mycompany.hellocore.App.main(App.java:26)
```

I also tried the same thing via maven on Eclipse, the error message is still the same. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

OS: Mac Lion /
Java version: 1.6.0_29

---

[Update]
01-6-2012 Based on Sri Sankaran's suggestion, i tried `mvn dependency: tree`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hellocore 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ hellocore ---
[INFO] com.mycompany:hellocore:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] \- edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.483s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 06 08:55:06 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The setting in my Netbeans:

[image]

But it seems like the library in need looks the same as what is already downloaded in Netbeans. The project still stops while `Adding annotator tokenize`.

---

[Update]
01-09-2012

After i reinstalled my system, the problem was gone. So i think the code and the module are both correct. The classpath directories might be just messed up by me. Thank you for all people's helps.

Just a gentle reminder for people using corenlp via Netbeans. In addition to the standard dependency of stanford-corenlp.jar. If you want to inlcude the stanford-corenlp-models.jar into your project. Seems like you also need to specify the `<classifier>` to add the models to the dependency repository.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include model (POS tag, NER, Coref, etc), so your annotator worked.
You can get it [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/1.2.0/stanford-corenlp-1.2.0-models.jar)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, even after i included it, this still did not turn out to work. I gave it up in the end and reinstall the whole system. Surprisingly, everything is back to life. Even though I did not change too much configuration previously, I think i might stil mess up something so it did not work as expected. All in all, thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The [usage of Standford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage) suggests that there are other dependencies.  If they aren't transitively included in the classpath by virtue of the stated dependency on `stanford-corenlp 1.2.0` you will have to explicitly state these other dependencies as well.  The command `mvn dependency:tree` should display your effective dependency tree.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I tried the 'mvn dependency:tree'. However, it seems like the essential things should have been downloaded (as additionally described in my post). But in the same way, it stil failed to build the tokenizer as the project stopped at 'Adding annotator tokenize'.